# How I can Import data from CSV to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I have csv file with following structure:

```
    A   BA0011  U206    NAME    0000000000000149.00     000000.00  0000000000000118.93  S   N   N
    A   BB0011  U206    NAME    0000000000000150.00     000000.00  0000000000000118.93  S   N   N
    A   BC0011  U206    NAME    0000000000000151.00     000000.00  0000000000000118.93  S   N   N
    A   BD0011  U206    NAME    0000000000000152.00     000000.00  0000000000000118.93  S   N   N
    A   BE0011  U206    NAME    0000000000000153.00     000000.00  0000000000000118.93  S   N   N
```

Using following MySQL Function How I can import first and third column in MySQL table:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY \t' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

I apologize for my English!

Thanks in advance !

Comment: See the CSV storage engine http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/csv-storage-engine.html for extra fun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the columns and mark the unnecessary columns as '@dummy'.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv'
INTO TABLE t1
(column1, @dummy, column2, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Replace `t1`, `column1` and `column2` as you like. To set other columns which are not in the data file, you can do it like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv'
INTO TABLE t1
(column1, @dummy, column2, @dummy, @val, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
SET column3 = "test", column4 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, column5 = @val/10;
```

For further reference, I recommend you to take a look at the [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html).

Comment: If you must use this code, the table must contain all fields that are in the file.

Comment: @dilyan_kn I added an example which defines some additional columns.

Comment: where shd be data.csv putted ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could import it into a table that has all the columns (to match the CSV), then select-insert it into your target table?