# Save CSV content into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm having a problem with insert csv into database. here's my csv content sample:

```
gender,age,name,location
male,21,jayvz,spl
female,21,jacyn,srl
```

and here's the table structure of the table:

- id (auto increment)
- contact_id
- label
- value

what I need to do is insert the data from csv to that table like this:
expected output:

```
id | contact_id | label    | value
1  |     1      | gender   | male
2  |     1      | age      | 21
3  |     1      | name     | jayvz
4  |     1      | location | spl
5  |     2      | gender   | female
6  |     2      | age      | 21
7  |     2      | name     | jacyn
8  |     2      | location | srl
```

(sorry for the expected output)

any ideas? or is this even possible?

CODE:

```
$headers = exec("head -n 1 {$paramfile}");
$param_names = array_filter(explode(",", $headers));
$param_count = count($param_names);

$contact_count = count($contacts);

$contactsfile = getcwd()."/uploads/".date('ymdhis').".cntctid";
$row = '';
$str_csv = array();

$tmp_handler = fopen($datafile, 'r');
$param_value = '';

while(($upload_str = fgets($tmp_handler, 4096)) !== FALSE){
    $param_value = explode(",", $upload_str);
    array_shift($param_value); // msisdn bb
    $str_line = implode(",", $param_value);
    //$age = array_shift($param_value);

    //$row.= implode(",", $param_value);
    //for($x = 0; $x < count($param_value); ++$x){
    //    $row.= $param_value[$x].",";
    //}

    $str_csv[] = str_getcsv($str_line, ",");
}
for($a = 0; $a < $param_count; ++$a){
for($i = 0; $i < $contact_count; ++$i){
$row = $contacts[$i].",".$param_names[$a].",'<the values should be here>'";
exec("echo '".$row."' >> ".$contactsfile);
}
}

$load_query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{$contactsfile}' INTO TABLE {$this->contact_details} ";
$load_query .= "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' ";
$load_query .= "(contact_id, label_name, label_value)";

$this->db->query($load_query);

return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can Import data from CSV to MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555370/how-i-can-import-data-from-csv-to-mysql)

Comment: Possible is almost everything. Please post your code so far.

Comment: @randak - yeah this is exactly what i've been doing so far, but the difference is that, I wanted to put the headers (gender, age...) as values for 'label' column

Comment: edited, i just show you guys my code

Comment: Why would you want a table like that?  You can't get useful information from it.  Normalize!

Comment: @dar7yl User defined fields would sit in that table nicely.

Comment: @h.coates you're right, im working on a profiling system and no one can tell how many user defined fields will be there, they may include one or more or nothing

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$row = 1;
$labels = array();
if (($handle = fopen("your.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if($row==1){
           $labels = $data;
        } else {
           foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
              $query = "insert into table values (null,$row,'{$labels[$key]}','$value')";
              $this->db->query($query)
           }
        }
        $row++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: One insert for each lineis an approach that works for huge CSV files too, but if you that the CSV data will always be small enough to fit into memory, I would set up a values array and insert once after that loop.

Comment: I will use a very large amount of data for a csv file (eg. 500k upto 1m lines or more)

Comment: thanks @HarryFink for your idea. however I need to execute the algorithm without exhausting my memory

Answer (score 1):

Why not use php to parse it for you? More control, less worries IMO.

To do so you would split it into lines, and then the lines into fields. The following assumes that you have the CSV available in a string variable, and that the CSV was created on the same system that you want to parse it with (due to my use of the PHP_EOL constant)

```
$csv 

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csv);

$load_query = "INSERT INTO table_name (contact, label, value) VALUES ";

for($i = 1 ; $i < count($lines) ; $i++){
    // Split the line into fields
    $fields = $explode(",", $lines[$i]);
    // Concatenate the insert values
    $load_query .= "({$field[0]},{$field[1]},{$field[2]})"; 
    // If there are more lines add a comma
    if($i < (count($lines)-1)){
        $load_query .= ",";
    }
}
// Run the query and return
$this->db->query($load_query);
return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;
```

These fields should really be sanitized or something though.

Answer (score 0):

this problem is solved, I wrote the data into a csv file in this format

1,age,21
1,name,jayvz
1,location,spl
2,age,21
2,name,jacyn
2,location,srl

then I used the mysql's load local infile query to prevent the memory from exhausting and as for very large files I divided it into multiple files as possible using bash script's 'split'

thanks guys for the ideas. =)