# Insert each line csv of data into database

Tags: mysql, csv, file-io

I have the following line to load csv file and insert into one table

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/html/portugal.csv' 
IGNORE INTO TABLE sample_upload 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(test_name)
```

Now it will insert first column into `sample_upload.test_name`    field.

I need to insert each line of csv file into test_name field.
Is possible?

Comment: Yes, but it's unclear what your problem is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555370/how-i-can-import-data-from-csv-to-mysql

Comment: @fancyPants I need to insert each line as one record

Comment: You mean you want to have it all in one row of the table? And you need to describe what is not working. Are there error messages? Provide sample data, current result, desired result and so on.